# How to get non-mapped column in a result of Doctrine native query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, nativequery, doctrine-native-query

How can I get non-mapped column in result from native query?

My query:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT m.id, m.title, MATCH(m.title) AGAINST('$slug') AS score "
            . "FROM music AS m "
            . "ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100", $rsm);
```

Column `score` isn't mapped in entity and I don't have access to its value from Twig. Is it possible to add this column into entity only for this query?

Comment: Did you try this? Does it work? Do you get an error? What is the error?

Comment: query doesn't get error but when I try display score in Twig 

I got this:

Method "score" for object "PlayerBundle\Entity\Music" does not exist in src\PlayerBundle\Resources\views\Default\search.html.twig at line 12

because score is not mapped in Entity class

Comment: I think you should just make sure your database model and object model correspond. Otherwise it will all become be very difficult and very buggy...

Comment: I have field "rate" in "Music" Entity and I can overwrite value from score but I need both field.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9833329/5759314)?

Comment: I want select fields that are created within a SELECT statement, not update. The problem is that Doctrine get values only for mapped fields which are mapped in Entity. I don't know how to map "score" field only in this native query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show score inside Twig template, you can try following steps:

1) Add $score attribute without any mapping configuration to your Music entity:

```
class Music {
    //Other mappings

    protected $score;

    //TODO: add getter/setter for $score
}
```

2) Add it to your ResultSetMapper:

```
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('YourBundle:Music', 'm');
$rsm->addMetaResult('m', 'score', 'score', false, 'integer'); //first 'score' is your DB alias
```

3) Call in your `search.html.twig`:

```
{{ object.score }}
```

Where object is your Music entity.

Additional information about pure and mixed results could be found [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results).

Comment: $rsm->addScalarResult have 3 parameters: ColumnName, alias, type.
I use only 2 parameters(because third is optional) and get result:

array:100 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => Music {#480 ▶}
    "score" => "12.595897674560547"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => Music {#561 ▶}
    "score" => "3.7423951625823975"
  ]
]


score is outside Object

Comment: @MonkeyOne Yes, true. I have edited my answer and also tested it. Apparently this is the only way how to do what you want.

Comment: I already have a "score" in the Music object but it's always NULL

Comment: @MonkeyOne Have you tried **addMetaResult** (you may also try to default 5th argument)?

Comment: yes, I tried with and without 5th arguments and still return null.

Comment: I use $query->getArrayResult(); to get result from query